# Digitally signed a pdf using java itext

Tags: java, itext

I'm getting the following error

> Error during signature verification.  Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data.  Support Information: SigDict /Contents illegal data

in this code:

```
public void signPdf(String src, String dest, boolean certified, boolean graphic) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException{
    String path = "src/sign.pfx";
    String keystore_password = "1234";
    String key_password = "1234";
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sign.pfx");
    ks.load(is, keystore_password.toCharArray());

    String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
    System.out.println("-alias------------>> "+alias);
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    byte[] pdfByteArray = null;
    // creating dynamic document using itext.
    Document document = new Document();
    OutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baosPDF);
    document.open();
    //document.load("audittrailview-1.pdf");
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    document.close();
    byte[] bytearrayb = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) baosPDF).toByteArray();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytearrayb);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baosPDF, '\0', null, true);

    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason("reason");
    appearance.setLocation("just");
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, "DVA");
    if (certified) appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
    if (graphic) {
        appearance.setSignatureGraphic(Image.getInstance(RESOURCE));
        appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
    }
    appearance.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
   // appearance.setSignatureCreator("santhanakumar");
    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");

    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    baosPDF.flush();
    baosPDF.close();

    BufferedOutputStream fs = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("myfile123.pdf")));
    fs.write(((ByteArrayOutputStream) baosPDF).toByteArray());
    fs.flush();
    fs.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PDf_gen signatures = new PDf_gen();
    try {
        signatures.signPdf(ORIGINAL, "", true, false);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: yes. I already generated digital signed a pdf. but when i open the PDF had error occured for above.

Comment: Please provide your code and the output PDF.

Comment: @Santhanakumar: It is better to edit your question, code doesn't format quite as nicely in the comments.

Comment: [edit] <-- click here

Comment: Please `reset` the `ByteArrayOutputStream` before reusing it for signing.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to reset the ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: @Santhanakumar did you notice that mkl formatted the words reset and ByteArrayOutputStream as code?